# MySQL Two databases, order by one column in one case, order by another column in different case

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have two tables. First table looks like this:

Table: Records

```
    rid  |   user id   |     title     |    whenadded    | public
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    1        212           Example        2012-06-28         1
    2        217           Test Rec       2012-07-05         1
    3        212           Another        2012-07-02         1
    4        212           Unlisted       2012-05-02         0
    5        217           Success        2012-04-08         1
    6        238           Always         2012-04-18         1
```

Table: Likes

```
    id  |   user id   |     rid     |    whenliked
------------------------------------------------------
    1        212            2            2012-07-06
    2        205            1            2012-06-30
    3        212            5            2012-07-04
```

In the 'Records' table, 'rid' is set as the primary index. In the 'Likes' table, id is set as the primary index.

I'm using PHP. PHP will provide a value to MySQL to use as reference. I'd like to have a single MySQL query that will do the following:

Pseudo Code:

```
$userid = 212;
$SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT records.* 
        FROM records,likes 
        WHERE (records.userid = ' . $userid . 
          ' AND records.public = 1) 
            OR (records.id = likes.rid AND likes.userid = ' . $userid . 
          ' AND records.public = 1) 
        ORDER BY likes.whenliked DESC, records.whenadded DESC 
        LIMIT 50;';
```

Look at the $SQL query I just provided above. That's my attempt at developing the query I wanted, but it didn't achieve what I was looking for; it came pretty damn close, but it was still ordering incorrectly. The query was developed as best as I could first by myself, then based on what I found by searching for a solution on StackFlow and elsewhere on Google.

Those are the conditions I'm trying to order it by:

1. All records selected must be public (records.public = 1).
2. If the record belongs to the user (in this example, 212), then order the records by records.whenadded.
3. If the record doesn't belong to the user, but it's a record the user liked, then order the records by likes.whenliked.
4. Dates would be ordered from newest to oldest.

The end result from the query returned would look like this (keep in mind, whenliked is NOT in the return data, it's just there for reference so you see how it's ordered):

```
    rid  |   user id   |     title     |    whenadded    | public   |  whenliked {not incl}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2        217           Test Rec       2012-07-05         1        2012-07-06
    3        212           Another        2012-07-02         1
    5        217           Success        2012-04-08         1        2012-06-30
    1        212           Example        2012-06-28         1
```

Hope that makes sense. Feel free to ask questions, I'll clarify the best I can.

Thanks in advance for your time, your consideration, and for reading this. Even if there is no response or no solution is found, your time is still very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Suggest to separate the query into 2 query and use UNION instead.

Comment: This is an out-of-the-question comment but your query looks weird to me. The DISTINCT seems to correct a mistake in the WHERE clause. I'll add an answer with an equivalent query.

Comment: Without DISTINCT, the query resulted in several duplicates, so I had to add in DISTINCT to eliminate the duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field you are ordering by doesn't have to be an existing field in the database. You can also use a field you define in your select:

```
SELECT IF(records.userid = ' . $userid . ', records.whenadded, likes.whenliked) as date
```

Now you can use it in the order by part:

```
ORDER BY date DESC
```

From the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

> A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses

Comment: Not sure how to work with that; it seems to do that, I'd need to do two SELECT statements in a single query. How would that work? I apologize if it's something that should be obvious. Your quick help and response was definitely appreciated!

Comment: You can just add it to your existing select. Just add it as an additional column you would like to retrieve.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around this: "IF(records.userid = ' . $userid . ', records.whenadded, likes.whenliked)" -- I can see the conditional where it's asking if the userid equals the given value. But how does whenadded/whenliked affect the IF formula?

Comment: Please refer to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a877/7 for @Dan solution. I do think this is a better solution than UNION instead. The IF is to satisfy the number 2 and 3 condition as specified by you in your description.

Comment: @Don Cullen: They don't affect it. The first part of the IF is the condition, the second is the case when it evaluates to true and the third when it evaluates to false. So you could read it like: IF the userid of the record is the given userid then assign the value of records.whenadded to the column date, otherwise assign the value of likes.whenliked to the column date.

Comment: Works perfectly! I'm also loving the IF conditional for conditional results, I didn't know about it, and can think of many cases where I'd have used it! THANK YOU, everyone!

Comment: A quick note; interesting result-- if the Likes table happens to be empty, the query will return absolutely no rows, even if there's records belonging to the user-- so the query fails. Easily fixed by putting in a fake row in the Likes table so it won't fail. But just wanted to toss that out here; thought it was interesting and was curious to see if you had any insight as to why an empty table would break the query.

Comment: Because you do a wrong join for that case. You create the cartesian product by taking only those results that have entries in both tables. If you do a LEFT JOIN instead you will get entries for all records regardless of the fact if they were liked or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to separate the query into 2 query and use UNION instead.

```
SELECT * FROM(
(SELECT records.rid, records.userid,records.title, records.whenadded as adate
        FROM records,likes 
        WHERE records.userid =  $userid   AND records.public = 1 )
UNION
(SELECT records.rid, records.userid,records.title, likes.whenliked as adate 
        FROM records,likes 
        WHERE records.rid = likes.rid AND likes.userid = $userid  
          AND records.public = 1)
 )t ORDER BY adate DESC
```

EDITED:
Please refer to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a877/4

Comment: Tried. Got error: #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY.

I apologize; I'm not familiar to working with UNION and two SELECT statements.

Comment: Could u please add in parenthesis? my mistake for omitting that.

Comment: I just took a quick look at your statement; issue is that there's several more columns in the Records table that also need to be returned. I simplified the table for the purposes of posting here at StackFlow. Your statement seems to only select four columns, so from what I understand, it'd only return those. Please correct me if I'm mistaken though!

Comment: You could add in the column as you want. I think its a good practice to specify which column to be retrieve instead of just asterisk.

Comment: Any particular reason why that's good practice? I'm always up for learning. :) Also re-ran your query with the changes. Got error: "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: You could refer to  [sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a877/4]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a877/4 . That is my practice (not necessary to be a good practice thou) due to i am using mysql with php. To make sure the column name is correct when retrieving to php coding.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$userid = 212;
$SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT records.* 
        FROM records,likes 
        WHERE (records.userid = ' . $userid . 
          ' AND records.public = 1) 
            OR (records.id = likes.rid AND likes.userid = ' . $userid . 
          ' AND records.public = 1) 
        ORDER BY records.userid, likes.whenliked DESC, records.whenadded DESC 
        LIMIT 50;';
```

This will separate the records-by-user and likes-by-user first and then by the date.

Comment: That resulted in records being organized by records belonging to the user, then the ones the user liked. It can't be organized like that; it needs to only organize around the date. This way, it results in a feed that looks like this:

Josh added a record called Neither on 02/17/2012
Josh added a record called Always on 01/01/2012
Josh liked a record by Somebody called What If on 12/24/2011
Josh added a record by Turkey on 11/12/2011

Make sense?

Not too sure how to add newlines here, apologies!

Answer (score 0):

According to my comment, here is another query that you should look at:

```
SELECT
    records.*
FROM records
LEFT JOIN likes ON records.rid = likes.rid
WHERE records.public = 1
    AND COALESCE(likes.userid, records.userid) = $userid
ORDER BY COALESCE(likes.whenliked, records.whenadded) DESC;
```

It assumes that you can't like more than once a record and gets ride of the strange DISTINCT.

Documentation for [COALESCE is here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

This query is not really performance-wise. If you have a really big database, spliting the query in two in order to user the indexes on userid at full power and then joining them again might be better.

Comment: While the database is currently small, it definitely will not stay small as it will quickly grow to large sizes and keep growing. So performance is definitely an issue. I'll go ahead and try your query though so I can tell you the results.

Comment: It returned results in where several records belonging to the user weren't included. At closer examination, your query seems to be not including records belonging to the user owns that others liked.

Comment: You're right ! Then my query is wrong and I'm starting to understand your DISTINCT :)